# Dropdown value reset to the first value in R shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a dashboard with four dropdowns. The region, market and submarket dropdowns are dependent dropdowns. I'm creating the dashboard as follows. Drop down for market reset to the first value in the dropdown. How to solve this?

For e.g for Region1 when I select MarketC it reset back to MarketA.
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

```
region <- c("Region1", "Region2", "Region1", "Region3")
market <- c("MarketA", "MarketB", "MarketC", "MarketA")
submarket <- c("SubmarketX", "SubmarketY", "SubmarketZ", "SubmarketX")

mod.selection <- data.table(
  Region = region,
  market_name = market,
  submarket_name = submarket
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
      values <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(Feature = character(0), Value = numeric(0)))
      observe({
        markets <- mod.selection$market_name[mod.selection$Region == input$select_region]
        updateSelectInput(session, "select_market", choices = markets)
        submarkets <- mod.selection$submarket_name[mod.selection$market_name == input$select_market]
        updateSelectInput(session, "select_submarket", choices = submarkets)
      })
    }


#Ui function----
ui <- 

  fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
                fluidRow(
                  column(3,
                         selectInput("select1", label = h4("Data Type"),
                                     choices = list("Unit" = 1),
                                     selected = 1),
                         verbatimTextOutput("value1")
                  ),

                    column(3,
                           selectInput("select_region", label = h4("Region"),
                                       choices = mod.selection$Region,
                                       # choices = list("Central" = 1, "West" = 2, "East" = 3),
                                       # choices = NULL,
                                       selected = 1),
                           verbatimTextOutput("value2")
                    ),
                    
                    column(3,
                           selectInput("select_market", label = h4("Market"),
                                       choices = unique(mod.selection$market_name),
                                       verbatimTextOutput("value3")
                           )),
                    
                    column(3,
                           selectInput("select_submarket", label = h4("Sub Market"),
                                       choices = NULL),
                           verbatimTextOutput("value4")
                    ),
                  
                  ),
                
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                  ),
                  
                  mainPanel(
                  )
                )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Please make your question reproducible.  We don't have access to your data, so can't run your app to test any potential solutions.

Comment: @Limey, I have added the data as you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: eg `mod.selection$Region == input$select_region` is a Boolean, so you can only ever select one row from your `mod.selection` data.frame.  You need to use `which`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? 
mod.selection$market_name[mod.selection$Region == input$select_region]
Here I'm subsetting the data table using the condition. It must have multiple rows of data, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a revised `server` function that I believe does what you want.  I've adapted your code as per my comment above and separated your `observe` into two `observeEvent`s as I believe this is more logical.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(Feature = character(0), Value = numeric(0)))
  
  observeEvent(input$select_region, {
    markets <- mod.selection$market_name[which(mod.selection$Region == input$select_region)]
    updateSelectInput(session, "select_market", choices = markets, selected = markets[1])
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$select_market, {
    submarkets <- mod.selection$submarket_name[which(mod.selection$market_name == input$select_market)]
    updateSelectInput(session, "select_submarket", choices = submarkets, selected = submarkets[1])
  })
}
```

Next time, please include the `library`s your code requires.